# how to make list with buttons at each item in Delphi

Tags: delphi, button, delphi-2010, tlistbox

As shown in figure, I need to make a list with buttons on each item, one button at down left of the item, and some on the down right.

I Make the demo app using `ListBox` control and some Buttons within Panel above on `ListBox`, but when the `ListBox` scrolling, it's difficult to make the Buttons follow the `ListItem`.

who can help, thanks~~~

[image: Pic]

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?  Are you using VCL or FireMonkey for your UI? For something like this, I usually use owner-drawing (such as using `DrawFrameControl()` or `DrawTheme...()` function when I want to create controls that use UI standard look&feel) to address the scrolling issue, then use hit-testing logic to detect clicks on the drawn portions to trigger actions as needed. Both `TListBox` and `TListView` support owner-drawing.

Comment: @Remy It still however widely depends on whether using `VCL` or `FMX`. Each requires an entirely different answer for this task.

Comment: I'm also curious why this question is tagged `web`, and why the sample image looks like it comes from a web page...

Comment: thanks for replies. I'm using VCL(version is Delphi 2010),this application will running on PC Computor and Windows OS. There is a 'web' tagged because of I think it seem like a web style list, and I did this demo using ListBox and some Colorful Buttons on it.

Comment: hi @RemyLebeau, In this UI Demo, I used owner-drawing style to make list content wrap words, but how to use 'DrawFrameControl()' function? could you say more about it please, thanks

Comment: @fengyq: I corrected the tags. As for `DrawFrameControl()`, [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480.aspx). For example: `DrawFrameControl(ListBox.Canvas.Handle, R, DFC_BUTTON, DFCS_BUTTONPUSH or DFCS_FLAT);`

Comment: Please don't add tags because it "seems like" something. Tags here have specific meanings. You should only add tags that actually apply to your question, and not those that *sound like* or *make me think of* or *sort of seem like*. Read the description of the tag, and only add it if it actually has meaning related to your question. Using the tags properly means that the question gets to those users who can help, and it helps make it useful to people who are looking for help solving similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the way to make it!so, I'll post the answer myself~, but Remy Lebeau inspired me.
in the beginning, I used `DrawFrameControl()` to make button on list, It works but the style was look like classic windows style, and it's hard to make back color like the pic in the example.
then, I used `FillRect()` and `DrawEdge()` make the Button, I think it's well, here is the code:

```
  hitPoint := lst1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  // there is a btnRect var of the Button Rect
  edgeRect.Left := btnRect.Left - 1;
  edgeRect.Top := btnRect.Top - 1;
  edgeRect.Right := btnRect.Right + 1;
  edgeRect.Bottom := btnRect.Bottom + 1;
  // make button
  lst1.Canvas.FillRect(btnRect);
  // make edge, FListMouseDown is bool var and setting value at MouseDown/MouseUp Event
  //
  if PtInRect(edgeRect, hitPoint) and FListMouseDown then begin
    DrawEdge(lst1.Canvas.Handle, edgeRect, EDGE_ETCHED, BF_RECT);  // button down style
  end else begin
    DrawEdge(lst1.Canvas.Handle, edgeRect, EDGE_RAISED, BF_RECT);
  end;
```

The following work is store the Rect of Buttons in memory, write the ButtonOnClick event code, and calling ButtonOnClick event at `ListMouseUp()` event after judge if Mouse Hit Position is in the Button Rect, The Code is not important like the above drawing Buttons, so it is omitted